# psql show me the : and ask user input, when running one sql file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I created one new database, then I am using psql to run this sql file(https://github.com/Arelle/Arelle/blob/master/arelle/plugin/xbrlDB/sql/public/xbrlPublicPostgresDB.ddl)
here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/psql postgresql://db_user:db_password@localhost:5432/my_new_db -f /tmp/xbrlPublicPostgresDB.ddl
```

psql show me the `:` , which is asking me to input something.

I checked xbrlPublicPostgresDB.ddl, which does not ask any user input. why does psql ask any user input?

Answer (score 1):

That colon `:` is not asking for user input. That's from the pager `less`. By default, when `psql` outputs something greater than a certain number of lines at a time, it will "paginate" it with `less`. You can see the same thing by running

```
cat /tmp/xbrlPublicPostgresDB.ddl | less
```

You can use arrow keys, page up, page down, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, and other keys to move around and see all the output. To exit, press <kbd>q</kbd>.

Paginating individual queries doesn't make much sense for what you're running, so you can disable pagination altogether when you run `psql` by setting the environment variable `PAGER` to a blank string:

```
PAGER= psql dbname -f xbrlPublicPostgresDB.ddl
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following parameter can stop that pagination, then I do not need to enter any key to continue. 
-P pager=off